# Why, sometimes, is it better to repeat?

Tags: word-choice, style

I want to explain to someone that sometimes it's better to repeat than to use a different word.

For example, if you use "satisfied", readers may think that you are talking about something else rather than the career fulfillment mentioned in the previous sentence. Also, using "fulfilled" makes the two sentences more connected because of the similar sounds of "fulfillment" and "fulfilled".

Are the two explanations I gave solid?

> Only when a person is doing what they want can they find
> **fulfillment** in work. Since **fulfilled/satisfied** workers are more likely to reach their full potential, I agree that the educated
> should be free to work in another country.

Comment: Yes, [elegant variation](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/elegant-variatio/) can be taken too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Students like simple rules that are easy to remember. Teachers like simple rules that are easy to teach.

The guideline to avoid repetition has some value. No one wants to see/hear a word like "awesome" repeated 5 times in one paragraph. THIS is what your teachers want you to avoid:

> My friend is awesome. He has an awesome boat. And his hair looks so awesome. He has an awesome smile . . .

The problem is obvious.

But many texts benefit from the repetition of significant words. In your example, the word **fulfill** creates a sense of coherence between the sentences. Readers (or listeners) will understand that you are discussing the same idea, and that will help them understand the text as a whole. Changing the word, even to a close synonym, might lose the connection.

A well-regarded textbook offers this advice that applies to your situation:

> Sentences are cohesive when the last few words of one set up information that appears in the first few words of the next. That’s what gives us our experience of flow. (*Style*, Joseph M. Williams and Joseph Bizup).

Your first sentence ends with the idea of **fulfillment**. The second begins with the same idea. The repetition is useful. In fact, very few readers will even notice it because the text is doing what they unconsciously expect a good text will do.

Teachers do not discuss this concept as much as they should.

Comment: Thank you very much for your amazing answer!